# Spring Hibernate MySql - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a running Spring Boot application with Mysql and Hibernate.

While launching it, i'm getting this error

```
Unsuccessful: alter table SMARTPARK.illuminazione add constraint FK_4kmtr3q9e2hnaoutsxgahhm63 foreign key (id_interruttore) references SMARTPARK.interruttori (id_interruttore)
2016-05-05 08:46:35 ERROR SchemaUpdate:262 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I have two table/entities

Illuminazione.java is (just the interesting parts...)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "illuminazione", catalog = "SMARTPARK")
public class Illuminazione {
    private int idilluminazione;
    private Interruttore interruttore;
    private Date dateTime;
    private Date lastDateTime;
    private boolean isLit;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_interruttore")
    public Interruttore getInterruttore() {
        return this.interruttore;
    }

    public void setInterruttore(Interruttore interruttore) {
        this.interruttore = interruttore;
    }
```

In Interruttore.java I have the `@OneToMany` relation with Illuminazione

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "interruttori", catalog = "SMARTPARK", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id_interruttore"))
public class Interruttore implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idInterruttore;
    private int numeroInterruttore;
    private String nomeInterruttore;
    private String descrizione;
    private List<Luce> luci;
    private GpioController gpio;
    private GpioPinDigitalOutput relePin;
    private Pin pin;
    private boolean remoto;
    private boolean stato;
    private Date dateTime;
    private Set<Illuminazione> illuminazione;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "interruttore")
    public Set<Illuminazione> getIlluminazione() {
        return illuminazione;
    }

    public void setIlluminazione(Set<Illuminazione> illuminazione) {
        this.illuminazione = illuminazione;
    }
```

Every time I start the application, during the boot i'm getting this error (even if the application seems working good...)

Comment: Is `idInterruttore` a primary key? If do why do you use `uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id_interruttore")`? How do you bootstrap Hibernate (update schema, create, do nothing)?

Comment: I do nothing with hibernate, the DB is already there, i just connect to it. I connect with SpringBoot default process

Comment: Looks like, Hibernate can't add `FK_4kmtr3q9e2hnaoutsxgahhm63`, because of your schema already has such constraint with other name.

Comment: @besmart, Did you manage to get the code working? I am facing the same problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check using normal **@Id annotation**

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error message, which I found out was caused by incorrect annotations. Hibernate was trying to run

```
alter table cidades 
    add constraint FKdt0b3ronwpi1upsrhaeq6r69n 
    foreign key (estado_id) 
    references estados (id)
```

And when I looked at my `Cidade.java`, I found this mapping

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cidade_id")
private Estado estado;
```

The error was in `"cidade_id"`, which should have been `"estado_id"`. It would be great if @besmart could provide the DB table info, since the error could be caused by a typo (e.g. `id_interruttore` could actually be `id_interruttori`).

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I hit similar problem .
To me apparently hibernate/Spring  was NOT using mysql Engine -INNODB , you need engine INNODB for mysql to generate foreign key constraint.
  Using the following properties in application.properties, makes spring boot/hibernate to  use mysql engine INNODB. So foreign key constraint works and hence also delete cascade

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: inspired by this answer, in my case I added this line `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

Answer (score 0):

```
I faced this issue when I have two entity one is Order_Details and other is Order_Items. Below is my entity

@Entity
@Table(name="order_details")
public class OrderDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="order_id")
    private Integer orderId;
    @Column
    private String userEmail;
    @Column
    private Double orderValue;
    @Column
    @CreatedDate
    private Timestamp createDate;
    @Column
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Timestamp updateDate;
    @Column
    private Timestamp deliveryDate;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="orderDetails",cascadeCascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGE)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<OrderItems> orderItems;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="order_items")
public class OrderItems {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="order_item_id")
    private Integer orderItemId;
    @Column
    private Integer productId;
    @Column
    private Integer quantity;
    @Column
    private Integer isDelete;
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id",nullable=false)// error line
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    private OrderDetails orderDetails;
}

Problem was @JoinColumn(name="order",
when I changed the name="order_id" it works, 
because order is a keyword in sql, we cannot use it as table name or column name.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).